# How do I differentiate between two json objects with same key?

Tags: javascript, json

I am need to find out how to differentiate between two json objects that have the same key - I am new to coding so sorry if theres something huge I don't understand :)

So in this json grabbed from the riot games API i come across keys like "leagueName" or "rank" and so on multiple times, how do I differentiate between these?

```
    [
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 29,
        "veteran": false,
        "losses": 25,
        "playerOrTeamId": "9673463",
        "leagueName": "Ezreal's Weaponmasters",
        "playerOrTeamName": "Battlerwinner",
        "inactive": false,
        "rank": "II",
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "a74b4b30-2dcb-11e7-bcd1-02953f14ecb7",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "leaguePoints": 0
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 109,
        "veteran": false,
        "losses": 102,
        "playerOrTeamId": "9673463",
        "leagueName": "Hecarim's Elementalists",
        "playerOrTeamName": "Battlerwinner",
        "inactive": false,
        "rank": "V",
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "73693cb0-700a-11e7-b5e7-02953f14ecb7",
        "tier": "GOLD",
        "leaguePoints": 64
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_FLEX_TT",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 13,
        "veteran": false,
        "losses": 17,
        "playerOrTeamId": "9673463",
        "leagueName": "Akali's Ravagers",
        "playerOrTeamName": "Battlerwinner",
        "inactive": false,
        "rank": "II",
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "f50c71a0-af99-11e7-91bd-02edcaa02cd3",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "leaguePoints": 44
    }
]
```

Id like to be able to differentiate the values of the keys and put them in seperate variables. I googled around and didn't find anything that I found helpful so I thought I'd ask here.

I tried a few calls I thought would work but I just got returned undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiate"? That's very vague. What *exactly* do you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab keys that are in a different object, like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
         ...
        "leagueName": "Ezreal's Weaponmasters",
         ...
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
         ...
        "leagueName": "Ezreal's SoulMasters",
         ...
    }
];

console.log( data[0].leagueName ); // Ezreal's Weaponmasters
console.log( data[1].leagueName ); // Ezreal's SoulMasters
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the examples of what you've tried, as well as to know what you are trying to do with the data.  You should be able to loop through the values with a jquery "each" to retrieve the values.

```
  $.each(json, function (index, element) {
    <take action on each element here>
  });
```

Comment: Don't understand the down vote here.  I gave an answer based on the info provided for how I'd access each variable.